# Would the atmospheric circulation experienced on my world's high platforms seem to be reversed?

Tags: science-based, physics, atmosphere, alternate-worlds, wind

In [this world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/217352/75), that rotates in the same direction and at the same rate as Earth, where the land platforms that cover around 10-20% of the world's surface is (magically) suspended at the 1 ATM level, 25km above a sea at which the atmospheric pressure is over 19 ATM, where the world's diameter is 22,282km, the gravity is 1g, and the [scale height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height) is equivalent to Earth's, about 8.5km.  The solar energy received is sufficient to make the land at the 25km altitude have a temperature of about 15°C on average, with a sea-level temperature of around 130°C (below boiling point thanks to the atmospheric pressure).

The world's real surface is entirely covered in water, over which is a thick layer of low clouds, about 5km from the surface.  There are also clouds above the ~25km platform altitude.  The troposphere is 35-45 km high.

The platforms range in thickness from 1km to 10km, and are like entire continents floating in the air, with mountains on top and also beneath.  They range from several hundred kilometres across to 10,000 km across.

Is it reasonable that the [atmospheric circulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_circulation) experienced by those dwelling upon those platforms would be the *top* of the cells, rather than the bottom, thus reversing the direction of the prevailing winds?

Comment: I wonder how thick are your platforms. Do they accumulate enough heat over the day to act like dry land in the earthly wind circulation mechanism? And actually what's the effective troposphere height (from real surface) on that world of yours? It's possible that it's actually lower than your platforms, meaning they have a very low precipitation rate, rendering your winds problem less significant.

Comment: @Vesper, I've edited in the size of the platforms.  The troposphere is going to be 35-45km high.

Comment: Hmm with these sizes of suspended plates I'd say not plausible, not enough arguments tho. See, having a platform 10000km across at 25km height creates an area of permanent night below, which could (and will) cause a major weather disruption, probably down to those wind cells not even forming, or attached to plates somehow instead of latitudes. I say you'd better go with normal wind prevalence, as I'm totally baffled at how to account for such areas that are permanently dark but transparent to wind.

Comment: @Vesper Most plates are going to be ~5000km across or less, and cover ~15% of the surface of the world.  The equator also doesn't have any significant amount of land over it.

Comment: I say a 500-km wide plate is enough to disrupt surface heating for your planet, together with influencing surface-based winds, as your planet is type ocean it won't have mountains on the surface to block wind currents "down there", and convection would surely be affected somehow. Since you're effectively asking about global weather patterns, I deem it necessary to account not only for what's happening right over the plates, but also of what happens under them. And that thing looks quite complicated even without those rocks, not sure if Hadley cells are even applicable to ocean-type worlds.

Comment: Also consider that at least edge regions of your plates would have serious updrafts from the west, as the wind meets a solid rock wall, and at times the cumulus clouds would hit the areas blocking off all visibility (or even light, like in the mountains here), when planning for the actual story. The eastern sides would have winds capable of throwing humans off the cliff, also more or less constantly dirested eastward. If there would be a jet stream-like current on your planet, it could effectively blow *everything*  off a hit plate, as they form at similar heights here.

Comment: Perhaps (story-based) you should just devise local weather at where are your heroes, based on local landscape, proximity to edges with respect to global tendency of having "below-ground" winds directed eastward and storing great power, occasionally pulling in a view-blocking cloud, a storm or heavy rain, and watch this go by. Prevalent winds would likely not really form, as your land is gapped, or would be dependent on plates configuration and not be actually defined globally.